# Manager multiple user calendar from a single program

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is it possible to manage multiple calendars from a single program? The task is to add events for different users in a domain, but do it from single program without knowing all users domain passwords. What type of authentication should be used to connect EWS? Is there any admin account exists? How to specify which calendar to update on each operation?

Answer (score 0):

sure is this possible. You will have to create an ExchangeService-instance for each user and set the ImpersonatedUserId property to the mailbox of the user you want to the appointment or whatever you want to add.

have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx there you can find how to work with impersonation and also have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204095.aspx where you can see how to set the rights your user needs to impersonate.

hope that answers your questions...